# Server placement for vendor verification check over the internet. DMZ or Private?

Tags: network, dmz

I have various servers on-premises on a private network. Some of these servers need to reach out to vendor websites to check for patch status, license verification etc.

Where should these servers be placed? Tn DMZ or can they remain on the private network?

If the on-prem servers are instigating a connection to a service on the internet using TLS, are there any risks to be worried about?

Is the general rule that if the internet service is instigating the connection then the company server should be placed on the DMZ?

Comment: The rule is that the connection should only be allowed to the vendor and not have unrestricted access, whether in DMZ or not. Where are they now? To place the servers in the DMZ, you expose them. The DMZ is for a particular type of protection and segregation.

Comment: @schroeder they are not placed anywhere yet. We are trying to make a decision. if i go with what your saying i.e. allowed to vendor and nothing else; then on premis should be fine. We can restrict traffic to vendor via the firewall.